# Why is my WPF component style changes when I change the architecture?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I am new to WPF and I can't figure out why my calendar style is not the same when I select x86/x64 or Any CPU.

It all comes from the idea to implement the calendar component developped by Charles Petzold in my windows application (https://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/10/Adapting-the-Calendar-Control-for-Week-Numbers.html). I call this calendar via a UserControl where it is alone in a grid, for the moment.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="NSxxx.Widgets.CalendarWeekNumber"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:NSxxx.Widgets">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <!--CalendarItem-->
    <Style  x:Key="calItemStyle" 
            TargetType="CalendarItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,0,3" />
 <Setter Property="Template">
 ......
 </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Calendar CalendarItemStyle="{StaticResource calItemStyle}" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Label Content="lbContent" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

In this application, I make use of the materialdesign package for other pages that I've made.

So far I managed to adapt the XAML of Charles Petzold to work with newer version of Visual Studio (ie. 2019), but when I select a specific architecture, I end up with 2 different styles:

- for x86 - the materialdesign calendar
- for x64 - the Petzold calendar (which is not printing the week number but that's another problem)
- for Any CPU - the material design calendar

When I remove the reference to MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf, it works perfectly in X86 - and still not showing the week numbers in X64.

Any ideas to solve this issue (apart to totally get rid of the materialdesign package - for the moment)?

Thank you

[X64 calendar vs X86 calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivaPz.png)

@Thank you Hostel for your interest !
Here is the App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="NSxxx.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NSxxx"
         StartupUri="NSxxxWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Indigo.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

CSPROJ is SLN ?
I've tried playing with the config and architectures, that's might explain the mess:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.31105.61
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Login", "Login\Login.csproj", "{8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "NSxxx", "..\NSxxx\NSxxx\NSxxx.csproj", "{8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SecurityFunctions", "SecurityFunctions\SecurityFunctions.csproj", "{F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WPF.FlipView", "..\FlipView\WPF.FlipView\WPF.FlipView.csproj", "{B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {8927619B-8A87-4050-B874-E0B0B8C2ADF7}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {8EC17DF2-B06C-43B3-88B7-838C92B9AB36}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|x86
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|x86
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|x86
        {F3DA1191-32A4-429F-AC26-67F77CB90F77}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|x86
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B6B0CDA6-CBE0-4D18-A213-C0F5D8100DD1}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {C28D41EC-44B2-4761-9AE5-32AF36C7AC03}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Could you show csproj? Do you have something custom in App.xaml?

Comment: `sln` contains a projects which are in `csproj` files.